# Swift iOS LineChart with different colors based on values

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I'm using [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library to make charts in my app. I need to create chart like the following one.

[image]

As far as I tried I managed to get like the following.

[image]

I searched for a day to find a solution, but I can't find any solution.
So if any of you know how to fix this or have any idea about this please do share with me. Thanks.

Comment: Override the renderer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve after lot of searching. I achieved this by editing the library files. See the [Pull Request at GitHub](https://github.com/thomashempel/Charts/commit/d05738a170830555c4662a5ab7a4141aa8765abe). Please change the files `LineChartDataSet.swift, ILineChartDataSet.swift, LineChartRenderer.swift` as shown in the `Pull Request` to achieve this.

Comment: Hi, Praveen i need your help,i cant find the pull request, i am facing same issue but unable to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

For a gradient line you can update your charts library to a version 4.0.0 or above. Or if you don't want to update you can make a custom line chart renderer of your own. I have made one for drawing a gradient line on line chart. Feel free to use it or make changes.

You will have to make changes to the gradient position to get your exact results though. And also provide your desired colors in the dataset.

```
class GradientLineChartRenderer: LineChartRenderer {
var _xBounds = XBounds()

init(view: LineChartView) {
    super.init(dataProvider: view, animator: view.chartAnimator, viewPortHandler: view.viewPortHandler)
}

func shouldDrawValues(forDataSet set: IChartDataSet) -> Bool
{
    return set.isVisible && (set.isDrawValuesEnabled || set.isDrawIconsEnabled)
}

override func drawHorizontalBezier(context: CGContext, dataSet: ILineChartDataSet) {
    guard let dataProvider = dataProvider else { return }
    
    let trans = dataProvider.getTransformer(forAxis: dataSet.axisDependency)
    
    let phaseY = animator.phaseY
    
    _xBounds.set(chart: dataProvider, dataSet: dataSet, animator: animator)
    
    let drawingColor = dataSet.colors.first!
    
    let cubicPath = CGMutablePath()
    
    let valueToPixelMatrix = trans.valueToPixelMatrix
    
    if _xBounds.range >= 1
    {
        var prev: ChartDataEntry! = dataSet.entryForIndex(_xBounds.min)
        var cur: ChartDataEntry! = prev
        
        if cur == nil { return }
        
        cubicPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(cur.x), y: CGFloat(cur.y * phaseY)), transform: valueToPixelMatrix)
        
        for j in _xBounds.dropFirst()
        {
            prev = cur
            cur = dataSet.entryForIndex(j)
            
            let cpx = CGFloat(prev.x + (cur.x - prev.x) / 2.0)
            
            cubicPath.addCurve(
                to: CGPoint(
                    x: CGFloat(cur.x),
                    y: CGFloat(cur.y * phaseY)),
                control1: CGPoint(
                    x: cpx,
                    y: CGFloat(prev.y * phaseY)),
                control2: CGPoint(
                    x: cpx,
                    y: CGFloat(cur.y * phaseY)),
                transform: valueToPixelMatrix)
        }
    }
    
    context.saveGState()
    
    if dataSet.isDrawFilledEnabled
    {
        let fillPath = cubicPath.mutableCopy()
        
        drawCubicFill(context: context, dataSet: dataSet, spline: fillPath!, matrix: valueToPixelMatrix, bounds: _xBounds)
    }
    let fillPath = cubicPath.mutableCopy()
    drawGradientLine(context: context, dataSet: dataSet, spline: fillPath!, matrix: valueToPixelMatrix)
    
    context.restoreGState()
}

func drawGradientLine(context: CGContext, dataSet: ILineChartDataSet, spline: CGPath, matrix: CGAffineTransform)
    {
        let gradientPositions = [0,0]

        let boundingBox = spline.boundingBox
            .insetBy(dx: -dataSet.lineWidth / 2, dy: -dataSet.lineWidth / 2)

        guard !boundingBox.isNull, !boundingBox.isInfinite, !boundingBox.isEmpty else {
            return
        }

        let gradientStart = CGPoint(x: 0, y: boundingBox.minY)
        let gradientEnd = CGPoint(x: 0, y: boundingBox.maxY)
        let gradientColorComponents: [CGFloat] = dataSet.colors
            .reversed()
            .reduce(into: []) { (components, color) in
                guard let (r, g, b, a) = color.nsuirgba else {
                    return
                }
                components += [r, g, b, a]
            }
        let gradientLocations: [CGFloat] = gradientPositions
            .map { (position) in
                let location = CGPoint(x: boundingBox.minX, y: CGFloat(position))
                    .applying(matrix)
                let normalizedLocation = (location.y - boundingBox.minY)
                    / (boundingBox.maxY - boundingBox.minY)
                return normalizedLocation.clamped(to: 0...1)
            }

        let baseColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        guard let gradient = CGGradient(
                colorSpace: baseColorSpace,
                colorComponents: gradientColorComponents,
                locations: gradientLocations,
                count: gradientLocations.count) else {
            return
        }

        context.saveGState()
        defer { context.restoreGState() }

        context.beginPath()
        context.addPath(spline)
        context.replacePathWithStrokedPath()
        context.clip()
        context.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: gradientStart, end: gradientEnd, options: [])
    }
}

extension NSUIColor
{
    var nsuirgba: (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)? {
        var red: CGFloat = 0
        var green: CGFloat = 0
        var blue: CGFloat = 0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 0

        guard getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha) else {
            return nil
        }

        return (red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }
}

extension Comparable
{
    func clamped(to range: ClosedRange<Self>) -> Self
    {
        if self > range.upperBound
        {
            return range.upperBound
        }
        else if self < range.lowerBound
        {
            return range.lowerBound
        }
        else
        {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

To use the renderer use this, where chartView is your LineChartView

```
chartView.renderer = GradientLineChartRenderer(
            view: chartView
        )
```